# How do I index an unknown number of fields in a nested document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have an embedded document and I want to perform a text search on it.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dd98c50f4351257b16ea7ff"),
        "author" : "Author",
        "apiid" : "235445623",
        "title" : "Test Document One",
        "url" : "test_document_one",
        "tags" : [
                "first",
                "post",
                "article",
                "sports"
        ],
        "content" : {
                "paragraph1" : "This is the first paragraph of this article but I changed it. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
                "picture1" : "https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/Brown_County_Hills_Leonetti.jpg?crop=33,0,1192,656&wid=4000&hei=2200&scl=0.29818181818181816",
                "paragraph2" : "This is the second paragraph of this article. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
        },
        "date" : ISODate("2019-11-24T11:12:31.890Z")
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how many paragraphs there will be and I still need the possibility to access each one individually. So if I do:

```
db.article.createIndex({ "content.$**": 1 })
```

I would like to do something like:

```
db.article.find({"content.paragraph*": {"programming"}})
```

and the * would do a regex on all paragraph fields so that the find query would run on all available paragraphs.

The result should be all documents that have the word "programming" in any of the paragraphs.

I could do it on my backend by querying all paragraphs and then do a for loop for every paragraph but I thought there would be a solution inside of Mongo.

I am open to any suggestions or tips,
thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organizing the content data as a set of sub-documents in an array, is one way to work with the issue. Each sub-document has fields like "para" and "pic".  To access a `para` within an article's content, use the index position in the array; e.g., first para is at `0` index, etc. The `content` field will look like this:

`content: [ { para: "para1's text...", pic: "pic-1's url" }, { para: "...", pic: "..." }, ... ]`

**Create a Text Index and Query:**

Create a *text index* on the `content.para` field:

```
db.articles.createIndex( { "content.para" : "text" } )
```

Query to find text in any of the paragraph's in the documents, e.g.,:

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "javascript" } } )
```

An efficient way of querying would be to restrict the number of documents to search the text, for example:

```
db.articles.find( { author: "phibiz", $text: { $search: "programming" } } )
```

*-or-*

```
db.articles.find( { date: { $gte: ISODate("2019-11-20"), $text: { $search: "programming" } } )
```

*NOTES:*

- [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions)
- [Storage and Performance
  costs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html#storage-requirements-and-performance-costs)